# Conexión MYSQL con AsyncTask Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio

tengo el siguiente método para insertar datos en una tabla MYSQL:

```
public static void Insertar(String nLocal, String nCliente, String direccion, String telefono) {


    String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO licencia (nlocal, ncliente, direccion, telefono) VALUES"
            + "(?,?,?,?)";

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    try {

        dbConnection = con;
        Log.i("LMO","con "+con.toString());
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

        preparedStatement.setString(1, nLocal);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, nCliente);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, direccion);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, telefono);

        // execute insert SQL stetement
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Record is inserted into DBUSER table!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

}
```

Este método creo que funciona perfectamente, pero a la hora de ejecutar la conexión quería realizarlo con AsyncTask porque de otra forma si intento establecer la conexión en el hilo principal la aplicación se cierra.

Este es mi metodo de conexión con AsyncTask:

```
private class Connect extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Connection doInBackground(Connection... strings) {


        try{
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL+DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return con;}

}
```

Este último código me da errores por todos lados pero esque no se como hacerlo correctamente, he estado investigando pero la gente realiza la consulta en el mismo doinbackground pero yo quiero realizar la consulta en un método aparte para que se ejecute en un onclick. Estos 2 métodos están en la misma clase, pero no se como llamar al doinbackground para que establezca la conexión en un hilo diferente al principal y asi recoger el dato de la conexión e introducirlo en el metodo de insertar.

Gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Tu base de datos es remota? En ese caso lo mejor sería programar en el servidor un Web Service que reciba los datos simplemente. Todo lo demás ocurriría en el servidor, no en la App.

Comment: Buenas, efectivamente tengo un webservice pero pensaba que de esta forma recibe los datos y los inserta en la tabla correspondiente, como podria configurar mi webservice para que realize la operacion de insertar y recibir los datos?  Un saludo

Comment: Es imposible explicarte en un comentario (ni siquiera una respuesta bastaría) para explicarte cómo configurar un Web Service. Solamente te muestro un punto de partida, luego debes investigar y decidir por alguna metodología para crear tu Web Service. La idea es muy simple, el Web Service recibe los datos, que pueden ir por ejemplo en la misma URL, y procesa la petición que le indiques. Puedes crear algo moderno, como funcionan las APIs, donde en la URL le indicas la acción y los parámetros, por ejemplo: `example.com/insertar/personas/` esa URL indicaría una inserción en la tabla personas...

Comment: ... los datos se pueden pasar en la misma URL o en encabezados (mapa clave/valor). También decir que este tipo de operaciones se pueden hacer también usando `Volley` de Android. Es más cómodo y claro hacerlo con esta librería que con `AsyncTask`. Pero eso queda a opción tuya. En la página `hermosaprogramacion.com` hay varios tutoriales muy buenos sobre Web Service para Android.

Comment: Gracias por darme las claves para continuar, investigaré y veré si puedo sacarlo de esta forma,  Un saludo

Comment: De nada. [Este es uno de los tutoriales de `hermosaprogramacion.com`](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/10/servicio-web-restful-android-php-mysql-json/). Es una página muy bien hecha, en castellano. Con ese tutorial aprendí de una forma **organizada** a programar mi WebService y a usarlo desde Android. Quizá al principio sea un poco costoso porque es como crear tu propio framework, pero una vez aprendidos los conceptos es una maravilla. Y además tienes tu propio código, tu propia estructura y una solución ligera sin tanta basura como a veces añaden los frameworks o APIs de terceros.

Comment: Lo único que no seguí de ese tutorial fue el uso de `XAMPP` y demás, porque yo tengo mi propio dominio con la base de datos MySQL en él. En vez de perder tiempo configurando todo el entorno de desarrollo que se explica ahí, programé todo en el sitio remoto y listo. También todo lo que es pruebas las hice directamente usando las URLs del sitio remoto, desde un navegador cualquiera. En el tutorial James explica todas esas herramientas de desarrollo porque él programó el WS en un equipo local.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, entiendo que al personalizar mi webservice se vuelve mucho mas funcional y rapido a la hora de hacer este tipo de peticiones, investigare los tutoriales que me has pasado y poco a poco ire configurando mi webservice, Un saludo

Comment: Es importante revisar el LogCat para saber si se esta registrando un error, tienes que revisar también si "con" se este inicializando correctamente.